# squared trace inequality for hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to prove that
$Tr(H^2)\cdot d - Tr(H)^2\geq 0$ for each $(d\times d)$ Hermitian matrix $H$.
This is equal to $d\sum_j \lambda_j^2-\sum_{j,k}\lambda_j\lambda_k$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$, but it did not help me :)
Best, Steve

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality: $tr(HId^*)=\langle H,Id\rangle$.

Comment: You are welcome